# Advanced Pivot Table in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have checked out the other two Pig pivot questions on StackOverflow without success.  This is a little different.

I would like to write a generic pivot function, where I don't know the schema up front.  To make matters worse, I need to pivot on an arbitrary number of columns and generate new columns, similar to how Excel pivot works.  For instance:

```
user year  make    model     mileage 
=======================================
123  2011  Ford    Taurus    19.2 
123  2011  Subaru  Forester  23.9
123  2012  Nissan  Altima    25.6
123  2013  Ford    Taurus    21.8
```

Let's say I want to pivot on the user ID and year in this case:

```
user year  Ford_Taurus_mileage  Subaru_Forester_mileage  Nissan_Altima_mileage
=================================================================================
123  2011  19.2                 23.9
123  2012                                                25.6
123  2013  21.8
```

The Excel configuration for the above would be two row labels (user and year), a single value column (mileage) and two column labels (make and model).

I'm starting to come to the realization that this is probably not possible in Pig, but figured I would post here just in case.  I have thought about having the user provide all columns up front (to the UDF) so the schema could be constructed, but even then how would I merge all of the rows together (for instance, in the case of 2011 where we go from two rows to a single row).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved this by writing a custom store function.  The user provides a list of Excel-like arguments: "row labels", "column labels", and "values".  The store function then uses checkSchema to get the original schema information and store it in the UDF context.  Next, when `putNext` is called, the new columns are created using the column labels and original value column names.  The row labels are just written out.  A `HashSet` of new column names are kept around.  Every time a value is written out, if the number of new column names has increased then we rewrite the new schema to disk (after deleting the old schema).

A couple of iterations through `putNext` would look like this for values:

```
123,2011,19.2
123,2011,,23.9
123,2012,,,25.6
123,2013,21.8,,
```

And this for the schema:

```
user,year,Ford_Taurus_mileage
user,year,Ford_Taurus_mileage,Subaru_Forester_mileage
user,year,Ford_Taurus_mileage,Subaru_Forester_mileage,Nissan_Altima_mileage
user,year,Ford_Taurus_mileage,Subaru_Forester_mileage,Nissan_Altima_mileage
```

There's no change to the schema on the last line because the input was another mileage record for the Taurus, which we already had a column for.

After all of the data is written out, we can read it back in using the new schema.  Unfortunately, this means that the first records to be written out will be missing fields (see the first couple of lines in the above iterations), so I also have to override the `LoadFunc` method `getNext` to call a new `applySchema` method that was modified from `PigStorage`.  This new `applySchema` method appends null values to the tuple if the number of fields in the tuple doesn't match the number of fields in the schema.  For instance, with the above example, our first row written by the `StoreFunc` would be:

```
(123,2011,19.2)
```

But the overall schema looks like this:

```
(user,year,Ford_Taurus_mileage,Subaru_Forester_mileage,Nissan_Altima_mileage)
```

Which means the first row is missing two fields.  Using the new `LoadFunc` we append the necessary number of null fields to make the tuple look like this:

```
(123,2011,19.2,,)
```

Now all that needs to be done is group the re-loaded data by user and year, and take the average of the remaining 3 columns to flatten things.

Answer (score 0):

Though questionable in its aesthetics, this is indeed possible. Pig doesn't know the name of all the distinct values your models and makes could take on, so you'll have to do an [embedded Pig script](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/cont.html#embed-python) and extract the levels of your variables.

This script handles *n* many models/makes and produces the kind of output you requested. To run it, type `pig -x local pivot.py` (or whatever you decide to name the file, if not `pivot.py`) with your sample data in the same directory.

```
import collections
from org.apache.pig.scripting import *
input_path = 'tmp.txt' #Set to whatever your input path and filename are
#First, we run an embedded job to find all the distinct levels of model and make
find_distincts = """
A = LOAD '$INPUT' USING PigStorage() AS (user:chararray
        , year:chararray
        , make:chararray
        , model:chararray
        , mileage:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE make, model;
C = DISTINCT B;
DUMP C;
"""
P = Pig.compile(find_distincts)
output = P.bind({'INPUT':input_path}).runSingle()
#Gather the models and makes from the output of the Pig script
cars = []
CarRecord = collections.namedtuple('CarRecord', 'make model')
for x in output.result("C").iterator():
        cars.append(CarRecord(make=x.get(0),model=x.get(1)))
#Next, we create a series of conditionals based off these distinct values
pivot_str = ""
cut_str = ""
#List of filters
for car in cars:
        cut_str += "%s_%s_cut" % car + "= FOREACH A GENERATE (make == '%s' AND model == '%s'" % car + "?mileage:0) AS mileage;"
#Output schema for rows we grouped by
pivot_str += "GENERATE FLATTEN(group.user) AS user, FLATTEN(group.year) AS year"
#Output schema for columns we grouped by
for car in cars:
        pivot_str += ', FLATTEN(%s_%s_cut.mileage)' % car + ' AS %s_%s_mileage' % car
pivot_str += ';'
#If you stopped the script here, it almost works--
#this approach yields duplicate records, so we have to enact a DISTINCT.
#It also produces every element of a (user,year) set, not just the
#intersection. To solve this, I sum the rows and keep only the greatest row.
sum_str = 'FOREACH C GENERATE user.., (%s_%s_mileage' % cars[0]
for car in cars[1:]:
        sum_str += ' + %s_%s_mileage' % car
sum_str += ') AS user_year_sum;'
car_str = "%s_%s_mileage" % cars[0]
for car in cars[1:]:
        car_str += ", %s_%s_mileage" % car
car_str += ';'
create_pivot = """
A = LOAD '$INPUT' USING PigStorage() AS (user:chararray
        , year:chararray
        , make:chararray
        , model:chararray
        , mileage:float);
B = FOREACH (GROUP A BY (user, year)){
        %s
        %s
};
C = DISTINCT B;
D = %s
E = GROUP D BY (user, year);
F = FOREACH E GENERATE group.user, group.year, MAX(D.user_year_sum) AS greatest;
G = JOIN F BY (user, year, greatest), D BY (user, year, user_year_sum);
out = FOREACH G GENERATE F::user AS user, F::year AS year, %s
rmf pivoted_results;
STORE out INTO 'pivoted_results';
DESCRIBE out;
""" % (cut_str,pivot_str,sum_str,car_str)
print create_pivot
create_pivot_P = Pig.compile(create_pivot)
output = create_pivot_P.bind({'INPUT':input_path}).runSingle()
```

The output, using your sample input:

```
123     2011    19.2    0.0     23.9
123     2012    0.0     25.6    0.0
123     2013    21.8    0.0     0.0
```

I assumed you'd like your null values set to zero, since a car with zero mileage should theoretically not exist.

Addendum: Another great resource, beyond the Pig documentation I've already linked to, is *[Programming Pig](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch09.html)* by Alan Gates, which, as of this post, is available in its entirety free online.

Comment: Unfortunately embedded Pig is only available in batch mode. We need this to be available in interactive mode at the Grunt shell so that analysts can pivot any relation that they wish on any arbitrary columns.  We don't know what the relations will look like up front, and don't know which columns they will pivot with.  I'm thinking that the way to go about this would be to write a MapReduce job and then use the MAPREDUCE command, but this means storing all of the data in an intermediate location and reading it back (and I'm also not sure if we can generate a schema for the LOAD phase).